# How do I get the Neo4J primary key back in a query result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the rest api, and cypher. How do I get back the primary key when doing a query like this for a node with some id that I have assigned to it?

```
{"statements" : [ {"statement" : "MATCH (n) where n.id = { id } RETURN n", 
                       "parameters" : { 
                            "id" : "1001"
                        } 
                    }] 
                 }
```

This will return

```
{"results":[{"columns":["n"],"data":[{"row":[{"id":"1001"}]}]}],"errors":[]}
```

Is there a way to get the Neo4J primary key as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, by "primary key", you mean the neo4j-assigned node ID, you can use the [ID()](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.2/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-id) Cypher function. For example:

```
{"statements" : [ {"statement" : "MATCH (n) where n.id = { id } RETURN n, ID(n)", 
                   "parameters" : { 
                        "id" : "1001"
                    } 
                }] 
}
```